# iterating a map of classes and invoking

Tags: java, dynamic, abstract-class

The invoke() here errors with: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class HelloWorld$Foo`, and I'm not clear why. I also had to resort to getting the string `.class.toString()` instead of using the `.class` directly.

Can you help me invoke the method, if not also avoiding the `toString()` call?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Map<String, Class> myMap = new HashMap<String, Class>();
        myMap.put("foo", Foo.class);
        myMap.put("bar", Bar.class);

        try {
            for(String name : myMap.keySet()){
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(myMap.get(name).toString()); // do I need to go through string at all?
                Object foobar = clazz.newInstance();
                System.out.println("name: " + name + " goes " + foobar.getClass().getMethod("chirp").invoke(foobar));
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
    public abstract class Foobar {
        abstract String chirp();
    }
    public class Foo extends Foobar {
        public String chirp () { return "chirp-chirp!"; }
    }
    public class Bar extends Foobar {
        public String chirp() {return "woof-woof!"; }
    }
}
```

edit: completed answer:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Map<String, Class> myMap = new HashMap<String, Class>();
        myMap.put("foo", Foo.class);
        myMap.put("bar", Bar.class);

        try {
        for(Map.Entry<String, Class> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
          Class<?> clazz = entry.getValue();                
          Object foobar = clazz.getConstructor(  HelloWorld.class ).newInstance( new HelloWorld() );;
          System.out.println("name: " + entry.getKey() + " goes " + clazz.getMethod("chirp").invoke(foobar));
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
    public abstract class Foobar {
        abstract String chirp();
    }
    public class Foo extends Foobar {
        public String chirp () { return "chirp-chirp!"; }
    }
    public class Bar extends Foobar {
        public String chirp() {return "woof-woof!"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo` is an inner class of `HelloWorld` and thus would have to be created by an instance of `HelloWorld`. Try `public static class Foo ...` instead.

If `Foo` needs to be an inner class (i.e. not `static`), you need to call the corresponding constructor, e.g. like this:

```
Foo.class.getConstructor(  HelloWorld.class ).newInstance( new HelloWorld() );
```

Note that the above is an example so you'd probably use `clazz.getConstructor(...)`. However, note that in this case if `Bar` is a static "inner" class there would be no such constructor for that class. Thus if the classes are different you'll have to check which constructors are available.

Also `Class<?> clazz = myMap.get(name);` is sufficient.

And a side note: You don't need a lookup in the loop, just iterate over the map's entry set. Also since you create an instance of `clazz` you don't need to call `foobar.getClass()` but can use `clazz` directly.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Class> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
  Class<?> clazz = entry.getValue();                
  Object foobar = ...;
  System.out.println("name: " + entry.getKey() + " goes " + clazz.getMethod("chirp").invoke(foobar));
}
```